# Discord.py scheduling with custom time intervals

Tags: python-3.x, mongodb, discord.py

I am trying to make a bot that sends quotes in servers at different intervals of time (defined by the server admins) by storing the channel id and the time interval (in seconds) inside a db. I managed to get it working for a constant amount of time (say 10 minutes) with `@tasks.loop()` but I cant figure out how to make it post at different intervals.

Answer (score 0):

Task loops have a method called `change_interval` which can, as you'd expect, change the interval, you can find out more on [here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/tasks/index.html#discord.ext.tasks.Loop.change_interval)